# d3 radial tree highlight path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I just have a quick question regarding changing the color of a path of a stroke of the stock radial tree by Mike Bostock

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

For example, if I can change the color of sub links such as:

```
var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return "M" + project(d.x, d.y)
            + "C" + project(d.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
            + " " + project(d.parent.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
            + " " + project(d.parent.x, d.parent.y);
      });


    link.attr('stroke', function(d) {
       if (d.id.startsWith("Root.Item1")){
          return "#386eff";
        }

        if (d.id.startsWith("Root.Item2")){
          return "#45cbf2";
        }
        else return '#70f2ad';
        });
```

This will change all the link colors for data that starts with Root.Item2

I.e. Root.Item2.Child1 and Root.Item2.Child2

will have the same color.

However, what If I wish to highlight the paths for Root.Item2.Child2 only and leave the other links the same color?

The concept is something like highlight the path that starts with Root and ends in Child2?

Thanks

Comment: The data object `d` should contain a `source` property that has a `depth` property. You can use that to conditionally highlight any depth.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out in a roundabout way by checking the d.children of the node. Not sure if it's ideal but it works if anyone else wishes to do something similar.

```
if (d.id.startsWith("Root.Item2")) {
                for (var i = 0; i < d.children.length; i++ ) {
                    if (d.id.startsWith("Root.Item2.Child1") |
                    ) {
                        return "red";
                    }
                }
```